# How to check if a json doesn't contain an array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am executing this query to get some records from a table. In the relationship `unread`, I need to get all the messages where the seen cell, which is of type json, that doesn't contain the member id and his type. the whole point is to get all the messages that the member didn't see, I save the member who saw the message as an array where the key is their id and value of their type ['1' => 'admin']

```
$chats = ChatsMembers::with([
    'unread' => function ($query) use ($member) {
        $query->whereJsonDoesntContain('seen', [$member->id => 'admin'])
            ->select(['id', 'content', 'created_at', 'member_id']);
    }
])
    ->where([['user_id', $userID], ['user_type', '0']])
    ->join('chats', 'chats_members.chat_id', '=', 'chats.id')
    ->select('chats.id', 'chats.name', 'chats.bio', 'chats.image', 'chats.status')
    ->get();
```

I tried the given code but didn't work, can someone check what is wrong.

Comment: If JSON value contains an array then its string representation contains `'['` char with even (maybe zero) amount of non-quoted doublequote chars before.

Comment: PS. Of course if you know precise path to potential array then you may test it directly.

Comment: Can you share an example of `seen` column data? The end structure of the JSON column.